# Identify an unknown capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I was checking in some bags at the lab looking for capacitors and found one full (a lot!) of green (ceramic?) capacitors.

The capacitors are green, round, flat, with two legs on each side, like so:

```
  __
 (__)
 /  \
```

The package image is:
 [image: Capacitor image]

The only inscription in the package is: 1/NPO

None of the multimeters on the lab has capacitance mode. Is there any way to identify what this capacitor is?

Comment: Another clue: somebody at the lab told me those were bought for a button debounce circuit.

Answer (score 7):

I vote for 1pf. NP0 dielectric is the one being used in smallest caps.

Comment: Voted in support, 1pf seems the most likely.

Answer (score 2):

What about putting it in an RC circuit and measuring the charge time using an Oscilloscope? Using a known fixed resistance you can calculate the capacitance.

Comment: Mmm that's a really interesting option, because we do have a DSO Nano v2 in the lab :D. I'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

Yes; use an LCR meeter or a better multimeter.

Comment: Thank you, but sadly we don't have any of these :(

Comment: If it's really 1pF it will be hard to measure.